# How can I recover my RAID 5 array after removing 3 or 4 of 7 disks?

Tags: boot, grub2, raid, mdadm

I'd like to undo what I've mistakenly done.  From Disks I removed 4 of 7, 2 TB disks from the software RAID 5 array.  I am unable to bootup and come to this:

> error: disk 'mduuid/**long UUID number**' not found. 
>   Entering rescue mode...
>   grub rescue> **blinking cursor**

I removed the last 3 or 4 disks from the array; can I just add them back and be able to boot?  Here is my output from ls:

> grub rescue> ls
>   (hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos2) (hd1,msdos1) (hd2) (hd2,msdos2) (hd2,msdos1) (hd3) (hd3,msdos2) (hd3,msdos1) (hd4) (hd4,msdos2) (hd4,msdos1) (hd5) (hd5,msdos2) (hd5,msdos1) (hd6) (hd6,msdos2) (hd6,msdos1) (md/1) (md/0)

I had a swap RAID5 partition as well.  Any help saving my data would be AMAZING.

Reference: [Grub2/Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting)

EDIT

> grub rescue> cat /proc/mdstat
>   Unknown command 'cat'.

Comment: I would recommend seeking live help for that, Specifically the IRC channel. If you do, please post how you fix it here for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way to delete my question, and the options for closing do not apply.  The answer to this is either to simply enter the repair function when Live Booting and mark all the drive partitions that were removed as part of md0 and md1 again (swap and RAID5 ext4), or the answer is very complicated and requires data recovery.  Neither were enticing.  It's probably best to focus more on not doing this sort of thing in the future than trying to fix it anyway.  Fresh start.